# Keep checking if statement in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to keep checking a condition until it is true? I know there is a while statement in PHP but was not sure if there is a better packaged way in Laravel.

Basically I am transcoding a video through AWS. I want the frontend to keep saying "Uploading" until I know the video is transcoded and saved in AWS and all info is in the database. The videos will be short, but still transcoding is not instant so if I do:

```
if ($job['Status'] == 'complete') {

      $submission = new Submission();

      $submission->email = $request->input('email');
      $submission->original = config('filesystems.disks.s3.url') . $original_key;

      $submission->save();

      return response()->json([
           'submission' => $submission,
           'message' => 'Upload Successful. Good luck!!!!',
           'job' => $job
       ]);
}
```

This if statement will be false right away. But if I checked again every few seconds it will pass after a little bit. Is there a pulse type function to continue to run that if statement every X amount of time until it passes? Using a while seems to be hitting `max_execution_time` the limit.

Comment: Did you try ```sleep(3)``` in the while loop? Sleep doesn't require resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be on the PHP side?

If JS works, I suppose one way would be to have a bool state in your JS to show "Uploading" with setTimeout() to check if the video is uploaded every x seconds. When it passes you can set the state to false, which would make "Uploading" disappear.

Also, don't forget to stop the setTimeout function when it passes.

Comment: I would prefer it on php side just so I don’t rely on the front end and I have to save some information passed back once it’s complete.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do it using PHP. A cron job might work for checking if data has passed to then save information.

Comment: I agree with @Vimona, You should do it on the frontend, keeping the connection alive even when it is of no use can ultimately choke the server. Your request thread will be idle and do nothing while the video is being transcoded and uploaded to S3. You can do some polling sort of mechanism which will poll the server every 30-40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there could be 02 solutions:

1) If I were you, I'd prefer to handle it in Frontend side with AJAX. This is a pseudo code to explain my idea

```
function uploadMyVideo() { // to be called once we confirm the upload
  var jqxhr = $.ajax( "/upload/url" )
  .done(function() {
    // call another ajax to set the status = SUCCESS
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // call another ajax to set the status = FAIL
  })
  .always(function() {
    // in case you need it
  });
}
```

2) You can use [Laravel scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) to call periodically (eg: every minute) a job which checks for completed status, and run the logic inside it. (it's a cron job with laravel way)